# Android Studio can't run or sync imported project with gradle files

Tags: android, android-studio, apk

I'm new with almost zero experience to Android Studio and i'm trying to change some settings of an APK.

First i decompiled the APK and then i imported it to Android Studio.

At this time, Android Studio shows me this:

[image]

My goal is to run the APK project on an emulator. This mean that i have to press the run button, which is disabled at this moment. After a research i made, i read that i have to sync the project with gradle files, but the sync button is not visible, as you can see on the screenshot above.

Can anybody give me a hint of what to do because i'm stuck here for a long time. Your help will be appreciated.
Thank you very much for your time!

Comment: Your project is not properly imported to Android Studio as "app" folder is missing. That's why run button is disabled

Comment: @Parul Could you please give me a hint of how to import the project with the app folder?

Answer (score 0):

You can't just Decompile an application and then using it inside another project as the new one.

The only thing you can do-use is, checking the java codes or xml codes of the written application to see how it works.

The point is, it won't work like that and you're doing it wrong. However, you'll be able to see not obfuscated java-xml codes inside the application. You can't just import it inside the Android Studio as a new Project like that.

Comment: Could you please give me a hint so i can do it right, or provide a source that explains what to do in this situation? Is it possible to modify the codes or not?

Comment: It is actually Impossible to do so. Because it generates smali files and so much more and you can't actually import it easily into a new project. The only thing you can do is checking the codes (java-xml) which is used for the app. But the point is, any developer will obfuscate his/her's application after releasing so, that will be even harder to see **even the codes**!!

Comment: Understood. Thank you for your help!